# Textillate-effect displays all unordered list items when combined with <a href="#"></a>

Tags: jquery, css, animation, animate.css

I am using Textillate to apply an effect on an unordered list.

This works so far so well. Unfortunately when I combine the Hyperlinks within the < ul > - Element, it displays all < li >'s of the unordered list when starting the effect.

I made a quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deschroe/9hskE/

Does someone have an idea why it hicks up all together in the first line?
Goal is, that it just displays one by at a time.

Here's also the code:

```
<div id="white_box">
  <div class="container white">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
        <h1>Recent works:</h1>
        <h2 class="tlt">
          <ul class="texts">
            <li><a href="#">1 Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2 Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#white_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:#FFF;} 

.container.white {
    background-color:#fff;} 

.container.white h1 {
    font-family: "pragmatica-web", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: -0.040em;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color:#515050;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.container.white h2 {
    font-family: "pragmatica-web", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: -0.040em;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color:#328ff5;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;   
}
```

Comment: Do you have a better visual if you remove the `.texts` class on the `<ul>` tag ?

Comment: It is not about the visual. 
In the end I deprecated it, because it doesn't seem possible.